# How to change a code of putting image within a label from desktop to project file

Tags: java, image, user-interface, netbeans, label

So I have this code It's work when the image at my desktop, I added the image at src file put I couldn't convert it can you tell me what is the problem? this the code it set the image to fit the label too:

public void ScalImage() {

```
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\ath3.png");
    Image img = image.getImage();
    Image imgScale = img.getScaledInstance(jLabel2.getWidth(), jLabel2.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon scaliedicon = new ImageIcon(imgScale);
    jLabel2.setIcon(scaliedicon);

}
```

I tried to say: ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("ath3.png");
didn't work

Answer (score 0):

So I have solved it I wrote like that

```
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("ath3.png"));
```

It's work for me. I wish I'm right